# Centering a DIV and adjusting based on browser dimensions

Tags: jquery, html, css, streaming

I'm building a web page to embed a streaming video in. I want to center the video both horizontally and vertically, while resizing (based on browser size, not manually) the video to fill the available screen real estate.

Here's the tricky part; This page has a navigation with 60px height, and the video must be in 16:9. I would like to be able to set a min-width and min-height of 800px width and 450px height. The video should not be able to overlap the navigation, so if it's a bit off center vertically, that's fine. I can use jQuery if necessary, although CSS(3) would be preferable. This page is mostly for private use, so I'm not worried too much about cross-browser compatibility.

I have no idea how to accomplish this at this level of complexity. My thoughts are to create a div that fills the rest of the page, and center it within that div with absolute positioning. Unfortunately, I don't know how to make it resizable and stay in the correct aspect ratio. If it helps, I'll be using both UStream and Justin.tv for this project.

Thanks.

EDIT 1: I can't figure out how to make the bottom div fill the rest of the page while subtracting the navigation. I thought `height:100%;` would cover it, but unfortunately that does the entire 100% of the page, including the 60px navigation.

Comment: Showing us some code would be helpful.

Comment: try using min-width: x% and max-width: x% in your css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this jQuery plugin: [FitVids](http://fitvidsjs.com/)

Horizontal and vertical centering with [CSS3 Flexbox](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/flexbox/quick/#toc-center) (limited browser support, but as you said, that is not a problem)

Here is the code (without vender prefixes to simplify):

```
.parent{
      display: box;
      box-orient: horizontal;
      box-pack: center;
      box-align: center;
}
```

Apply that to the parent of the video.

Now the navigation shouldn't interrupt the centering, but in the case that it does, you can always `absolute`ly position the navigation bar. There will be some video clipped at the top, but 60px isn't that bad.

Comment: Answers the biggest part, I can work out the rest. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
<div class="greenBorder" style="display: table; height: 400px; #position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
    <div style=" #position: absolute; #top: 50%;display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
      <div class="greenBorder" style=" #position: relative; #top: -50%">
        any text<br>
        any height<br>
        any content, for example generated from DB<br>
        everything is vertically centered
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it :

```
var videoElement = $("#IDofYourVideo");

function SizeUpVideo(elm) {
    var W = parseInt($(window).width()),   //get browser width
        H = parseInt($(window).height()),  //get browser height
        ratio = 16/9,                      //set ratio
        videoH = H-60,                     //subtract 60px
        videoW = H * ratio;                //set width according to ratio

    if (videoW > W) {videoW=W; videoH=W*(1/ratio);} //if width is more than screen, do it the other way around
    if (videoW >= '800' || videoH >= '450') {
        elm.css({top: (H-videoH+60)/2, left: (W-videoW)/2, height: videoH, width: videoW});
    } else {
        elm.css({top: 60, height: 450, width: 800});
    }
};

SizeUpVideo(videoElement);

$(window).bind("resize", function() {
    SizeUpVideo(videoElement);
});
```

Fiddle :  http://jsfiddle.net/bAXwK/